# Create Record That is Tied To Another Table's ID -- Not Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying to save a record so that this table (proposal) saves it under another table's ID (client). So the create link is on the "details" view template because when I click on the detail of that table (client), has a link to create a new record (proposal) under it.

I did exactly how I've done this on another table where the client belongs to another table and has a link for creating a record so that when it creates should just open the create view template and shows the associated ID and saves it when submitted (rather than the scaffolded drop down select option).

HTML (conceptual)

```
CREATE link (which creates a proposal record under the client, see VIEW below)
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? clientId)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Create a Proposal";
        ViewBag.PanelColor = "success";

        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientId", "FullName");
        var proposal = new Proposal();
        proposal.ClientId = (int)clientId;
        return View(proposal);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Proposal proposal)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Create a Proposal";
        ViewBag.PanelColor = "success";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var client = db.Clients.Single(c => c.ClientId == proposal.ClientId);
            client.Proposals.Add(proposal);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientId", "FullName", proposal.ClientId);
        return View(proposal);
    }
```

VIEW (starting view where the POST happens)

```
@model AppName.Models.Client
...
<a href="/proposal/create?ClientId=@Model.ClientId">CREATE</a> // yes I could use the helper as well, but that's not the point
```

VIEW (The actual create view -- it's just the vanilla scaffolded view)

```
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                            <div>

                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Client</legend>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Client Full Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            @Html.DropDownList("ClientId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>

                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Proposal Details</legend>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Design</label>

                                        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Carrier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Carrier" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Carrier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Product" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Benefit Amount</label>


                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BenefitAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Benefit amount" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BenefitAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Date Created</label>

                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCompleted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCompleted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </fieldset>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

ERROR

```
Not savin
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have here is a simple HTML link, which by default will issue a GET request for the specified `href`. That will presumably then call the only action you've posted here that responds to GET, the first `Create`. This action assigns the id to `ClientId`, but importantly *does not save anything*, so I'm not sure why you're expecting something else to happen.

If you want to hit the POST action, you'd need to actually POST the data in your form, which would typically require an actual form tag and a submit button. If you want to use a simple link, you'd need to bind a click event handler to that which would either manually post a form (which is kind of silly) or submit the post via AJAX, by collecting the form data and submitting it all at once to the URL specified in that AJAX call.

You may be tempted to simply add some sort of saving capability to the GET action, but that would be a mistake. A GET should never modify anything. All atomic actions should be handled via POST or a more appropriate verb such as PUT, DELETE, etc.

Finally, you should avoid using `Bind`. It's the worst thing ever, and only serves to make your code fragile and prone to error. For more information, see: [Bind is Evil](https://cpratt.co/bind-is-evil/).

Comment: Made an edit. Basically, on my view, there is a link to create a record. Then this link opens the 'create form'. On the URL makes sure that this view would be under a particular ID. But when I click on the submit button. Not saving.

Comment: Well, the post action is pretty simple. If it's not saving, the only logical cause would be that `ModelState.IsValid` is false. If you're not seeing any specific errors on page, you might want to remove the `true` param from `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`, which will then cause it show all errors, not just model-level errors. It's possible there's a property you didn't expect to have validation errors that does in fact have validation errors.

Comment: DIdn't think of that yes I did the debugging. And I forgot that I added a column and added an input box. Now it's saving.